# spring boot handling for TCP/IP server

Tags: java, spring-boot, sockets, tcp, ethernet

Have to implement a server for handling the following protocol through Ethernet connection:

```
Establishing a connection
The client connects to the configured server via TCP / IP.
After the connection has been established, the client initially sends a heartbeat message to the
Server:

{
  "MessageID": "Heartbeat"
}

Response:
{
  "ResponseCode": "Ok"
}

Communication process
To maintain the connection, the client sends every 10 seconds when inactive
Heartbeat message.
Server and client must close the connection if they are not receiving a message for longer than 20 seconds.
An answer must be given within 5 seconds to request. 
If no response is received, the connection must also be closed.
The protocol does not contain numbering or any other form of identification.
Communication partner when sending the responses makes sure that they are in the same sequence.

Message structure:
The messages are embedded in an STX-ETX frame.
STX (0x02) message ETX (0x03)
An `escaping` of STX and ETX within the message is not necessary since it is in JSON format

Escape sequence are following:
```

> JSON.stringify ({"a": "\ x02 \ x03 \ x10"}) → "{" a \ ": " \ u0002 \ u0003 \ u0010 \ "}"

Not only heartbeat messages should be used. A typical message should be like:

```
{
  "MessageID": "CheckAccess"
  "Parameters": {
    "MediaType": "type",
    "MediaData": "data"
  }
}
```

And the appropriate response:

```
{
  "ResponseCode":   "some-code",
  "DisplayMessage": "some-message",
  "SessionID":      "some-id"
}
```

It should be a multi-client server. And protocol doesn't have any identification.
However, we have to identify the client at least the IP address from which it was sent.

Could not find some solution on how to add such server to Spring Boot application and enable on startup & handle input and output logic for it.
Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

---

**Solution**

Configured following for TCP server:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TCPServer {
    private final InetSocketAddress hostAddress;
    private final ServerBootstrap serverBootstrap;

    private Channel serverChannel;

    @PostConstruct
    public void start() {
        try {
            ChannelFuture serverChannelFuture = serverBootstrap.bind(hostAddress).sync();
            log.info("Server is STARTED : port {}", hostAddress.getPort());

            serverChannel = serverChannelFuture.channel().closeFuture().sync().channel();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void stop() {
        if (serverChannel != null) {
            serverChannel.close();
            serverChannel.parent().close();
        }
    }
}
```

`@PostConstruct` launches server during startup of an application.

Configuration for it as well:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableConfigurationProperties(NettyProperties.class)
public class NettyConfiguration {

    private final LoggingHandler loggingHandler = new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.DEBUG);
    private final NettyProperties nettyProperties;

    @Bean(name = "serverBootstrap")
    public ServerBootstrap bootstrap(SimpleChannelInitializer initializer) {
        ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
        bootstrap.group(bossGroup(), workerGroup())
                .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                .handler(loggingHandler)
                .childHandler(initializer);
        bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, nettyProperties.getBacklog());
        bootstrap.childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, nettyProperties.isKeepAlive());
        return bootstrap;
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdownGracefully")
    public NioEventLoopGroup bossGroup() {
        return new NioEventLoopGroup(nettyProperties.getBossCount());
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdownGracefully")
    public NioEventLoopGroup workerGroup() {
        return new NioEventLoopGroup(nettyProperties.getWorkerCount());
    }

    @Bean
    @SneakyThrows
    public InetSocketAddress tcpSocketAddress() {
        return new InetSocketAddress(nettyProperties.getTcpPort());
    }
}
```

Initialization logic:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SimpleChannelInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

    private final StringEncoder stringEncoder = new StringEncoder();
    private final StringDecoder stringDecoder = new StringDecoder();

    private final QrReaderProcessingHandler readerServerHandler;
    private final NettyProperties nettyProperties;

    @Override
    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = socketChannel.pipeline();

        pipeline.addLast(new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(1024 * 1024, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
        pipeline.addLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(nettyProperties.getClientTimeout()));
        pipeline.addLast(stringDecoder);
        pipeline.addLast(stringEncoder);
        pipeline.addLast(readerServerHandler);
    }
}
```

Properties configuration:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "netty")
public class NettyProperties {
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1000, max = 65535)
    private int tcpPort;

    @Min(1)
    @NotNull
    private int bossCount;

    @Min(2)
    @NotNull
    private int workerCount;

    @NotNull
    private boolean keepAlive;

    @NotNull
    private int backlog;

    @NotNull
    private int clientTimeout;
}
```

and a snippet from `application.yml`:

```
netty:
  tcp-port: 9090
  boss-count: 1
  worker-count: 14
  keep-alive: true
  backlog: 128
  client-timeout: 20
```

And handler is quite trivial.

Checked locally by running at the console:

> telnet localhost 9090

It works fine there. I hope it will be fine for access from clients.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the protocol is NOT based on top of HTTP (unlike WebSocket which piggyback on HTTP in the first place), your only option is to ***use TCP server yourself*** and wire it up within spring context to gain full advantage of spring along with.

**Netty** is best known for low-level TCP/IP communication and it's easy to wrap up Netty server within spring app.

In fact, spring boot provides [Netty HTTP server](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-reactor-netty) out of the box but ***this is not what you need***.

[TCP communication server with Netty And SpringBoot](https://github.com/zbum/netty-spring-example) project is a simple and effective example of what you need.

Take a look at [TCPServer](https://github.com/zbum/netty-spring-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/zbum/example/socket/server/netty/TCPServer.java) from this project which uses Netty's ServerBootstrap for starting custom TCP server.

Once you have the server, you can wire up either ***Netty codecs*** OR ***Jackson*** OR any other message converter as you seem fit for your application domain data ***marshalling/unmarshalling***.

[Update - July 17, 2020]
Against the updated understanding of the question (both HTTP and TCP requests are terminating on the same endpoint), following is the updated solution proposal

```
                ----> HTTP Server (be_http)
               |
----> HAProxy -
               |
                ----> TCP Server (be_tcp)
```

Following changes/additions are required for this solution to work:

1. Add Netty based listener in your existing spring boot app OR create a separate spring boot app for TCP server. Say this endpoint is listening for TCP traffic on port 9090
2. Add HAProxy as the terminating endpoint for ingress traffic
3. Configure HAProxy so that it sends all HTTP traffic to your existing spring boot HTTP endpoint (mentioned as be_http) on port 8080
4. Configure HAProxy so that all non HTTP traffic is sent to the new TCP spring boot endpoint (mentioned as be_tcp) on port 9090.

Following HAProxy configuration will suffice. These are excerpt which are relevant for this problem, please add other HAProxy directives as applicable for normal HAProxy setup:

```
           
listen 443
  mode tcp
  bind :443 name tcpsvr
  /* add other regular directives */
  tcp-request inspect-delay 1s
  tcp-request content accept if HTTP
  tcp-request content accept if !HTTP
  use-server be_http if HTTP
  use-server be_tcp if !HTTP
  /* backend server definition */
  server be_http 127.0.0.1:8080
  server be_tcp 127.0.0.1:9090 send-proxy
```

Following HAProxy documentation links are particularly useful

1. [Fetching samples from buffer contents - Layer 6](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.0/configuration.html#7.3.5)
2. [Pre-defined ACLs](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.0/configuration.html#7.4)
3. [tcp-request inspect-delay](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.0/configuration.html#tcp-request%20inspect-delay)
4. [tcp-request content](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.0/configuration.html#tcp-request%20content)

Personally I'll play around and validate ***tcp-request inspect-delay*** and adjust it as per actual needs since this has potential for adding delay in request in worst case scenario where connection has been made but no contents are available yet to evaluate if request is HTTP or not.

Addressing the need for ***we have to identify the client at least the IP address from which it was sent***, you have an option to use [Proxy Protocol](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/haproxy/proxy-protocol/) while sending it back to backend. I have updated the sample config above to include proxy protocol in be_tcp (added send_proxy). I have also removed send_proxy from be_http since it's not needed for spring boot, instead you'll likely rely upon regular X-Forwarded-For header for be_http backend instead.

Within be_tcp backend, you can use Netty's [HAProxyMessage](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/codec/haproxy/HAProxyMessage.html) to get the actual source IP address using [sourceAddress()](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/codec/haproxy/HAProxyMessage.html#sourceAddress--) API. All in all, this is a workable solution. I myself have used HAProxy with proxy protocol (at both ends, frontend and backend) and it's much more stable for the job.

Comment: If web sockets had an option for spring this how would look configuration will look like? We have different request bodies sent to the same endpoint.

Comment: @nazar_art, in your case (as far as I have understood) the protocol is NOT using http as it's base. WebSocket uses HTTP as its base, as part of handshake, the initial connection is made using HTTP which is later upgraded to WebSocket. spring already have support for web socket for long ([one example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/)) but that's not what you need since the protocol outline you mentioned does not confirm to http. It's a raw socket on which PDUs (Protocol Data Units) are exchanged.

Comment: for sure STOMP it SockJS wouldn't work for sure for this case.

Comment: Given example (STOMP over websocket), uses protocols in following layers - stomp messages encapsulated in WebSocket frames which in turn piggy back on HTTP. There are numerous examples which'll show you how to work with plain WebSocket. [This is another example](https://www.nexmo.com/blog/2018/10/08/create-websocket-server-spring-boot-dr) which doesn't uses STOMP but pure vanilla WebSocket. Bottom line, websocket is NOT going to work in scenario you provided based on protocol outline you shared in the question. Let me know if I have missed anything in the question or the protocol outline.

Comment: you understood it really well. I just want to know how to solve such situation when you have one endpoint but different request messages sent to it.

Comment: Ok got it now, basically you have only ONE endpoint on which you must intercept both (HTTP and this custom protocols) the protocols - somehow I it wasn't clear to me so far. That's more like protocol multiplexing and usually demand additional frontend layer. Do you have any specifics on which you can identify which protocol is expected - in simplest words, do you expect custom protocol to be used by upfront known source IP addresses only? It'll help in narrowing down appropriate solution.

Comment: I saw your update and just want to clarify what exactly this HAProxy should do? It should separate requests between app and TCP server?

Comment: that's precisely what HAProxy is introduced for. It'll be able to receive BOTH the protocols (HTTP and raw TCP) on **SINGLE** endpoint, inspect the payload and forward it accordingly to one of the two backends (be_http or be_tcp).